# Is the second "t" silent in the word "twenty"?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters

I have always pronounced the word "twenty" as "twen·tee" and taught my daughter accordingly. But she told me that her pre-kindergarten teacher pronounced it as "twen·nee", making the second "t" silent.

Which pronunciation is correct? Do we ever have a silent "t" in similar situations?